# How To define command from server for telegram BOT

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I've created a bot with @botfather and it's all okay . Now i want to set command from my host to telegram . i created a **Bot.php** in my root directory .

**Bot.php**

```
$string = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

    function objectToArray( $object )
    {
        if( !is_object( $object ) && !is_array( $object ) )
        {
            return $object;
        }
        if( is_object( $object ) )
        {
            $object = get_object_vars( $object );
        }
        return array_map( 'objectToArray', $object );
    }

    $result = objectToArray($string);
    $user_id = $result['message']['from']['id'];
    $text = $result['message']['text'];
    if($text == 'Hi')
    $text_reply = 'Hi';
if($text == 'Your name')
    $text_reply = 'jJoe';

    $token = '';
    $text_reply = 'Got you Buddy.';

    $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.tokenNumber.'/sendMessage?chat_id='.$user_id;
    $url .= '&text=' .$text_reply;


    $res = file_get_contents($url);
```

Now when i browse this :`https://api.telegram.org/bot112186325:tokenNumber/setWebhook?url=https://partamsms.ir/bot.php`

I get this : `{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}`

But i can't run these commands in my telegram account .

How can i Run commands from my server ?

Thanks a million

Comment: Can you perhaps clarify what you mean by "commands"? Do you mean that you don't receive the "Got you Buddy" message or do you want to send a message without it being a response to a message received?

Comment: yes sure , for example i want to get "jJoe" when i write /Yourname in telegram @ChrisBrand thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

According to your comment, you want something that will respond differently based on the message the user typed. So using your example code, you can change it to be something like this:

```
// NOTE: you can pass 'true' as the second argument to decode as array
$result= json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
error_log(print_r($result, 1), 3, '/path/to/logfile.log');

$user_id = $result['message']['from']['id'];
$text = $result['message']['text'];

// TODO: use something like strpos() or strcmp() for more flexibility
switch (true)
{
    case $text == '/hi':
        $text_reply = 'Hello';
        break;

    case $text == '/yourname':
        // TODO: use the getMe API call to get the bot information
        $text_reply = 'jJoe';
        break;

    default:
        $text_reply = 'not sure what you want?';
        break;
}

$token = '';
$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.tokenNumber.'/sendMessage?chat_id='.$user_id;
$url .= '&text=' .$text_reply;
$res = file_get_contents($url);
```

So, this is pretty much a slight refactor of what you already had...if the issue is that your **Bot.php** script is not triggering, it is possibly because the page is not public. The webhook you specify to Telegram must be a publicly accessible URL. I tried to hit https://partamsms.ir/bot.php and I can't get to it.

An alternative is to use the `getUpdates` method instead and to cron the script to run every 5 seconds or so.

Comment: thanks , a noob question : so if i type hi in telegram should get Hello ?

Comment: Yeah, if your webhook is working correctly. I updated my script with some error log information. If the file specified contains message information, it means that your webhook is receiving data from telegram and then if the message is "hi"...you should receive "Hello". If the log file is empty, it means your script is not accessible via the internet.

Comment: see the second line of the sample code for the added debug logging.

Comment: now when i type hi in my telegram bot , i get nothing and webhook is working correctly

Comment: Are you chatting to the bot in a group or a private chat, what do you type to the bot in Telegram? You might need to include the "/" if that is what you prefix with, debug the `$text` variable to see what Telegram passes to you.

Comment: also, update the link you posted in the comments to remove your bot token ;)

Comment: Updated :) just wanted to show you webhook ,i've tried both hi and /hi and i'm chatting in private

Comment: Actually i'm a frontend developer and i don't know how to debug that in Cpanel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84083/discussion-between-chris-brand-and-sani).

Comment: check your email @Chris